# How do I force my header table row to be the same height as the other table rows?

Tags: html, css, html-table, height, css-tables

I want all my rows, even my table header row, to be the same height.  I added this to my stylesheet

```
#currencyTable tr {
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

but if you look at my fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/4qmmeqsk/, you'll notice the header row is not the same height as the other rows (at least it doesn't have the same padding).  How do I make my header row the same height as my other table rows?

Comment: add a style `th` to your CSS and give it either padding or height. Like so: `th { padding:10px; }` or `th { height:20px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your th the same padding as the td:

```
padding: 12px;
```

or:

```
padding: 12px 0; // top and bottom
```

For your project:

```
th {    
   padding: 12px 0;
}
```

If you want to keep the background smaller, use margin:

```
margin: 12px;
```

or:

```
margin: 12px 0; // top and bottom
```

For your project:

```
th {    
   margin: 12px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "min-height" css doesn't really do much of anything, it's more useful for responsive design.  You can set an absolute height, with a max height, or increase the padding.

```
#currencyTable tr,th { height: 30px; max-height: ...px; }
```